# Preset SelectListItems.Selected in Bootstrap Multiselect

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

In my MVC project I am using a DropDownList with Bootstrap Multiselect. I have a jquery onChange event that takes the Selected Items from the list and adds them to a text box (which is linked to the view property) for storing in a database field. The controls are configured as follows :-

```
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.siteNames, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
                @Html.ListBox("SiteList", new SelectList(Model.siteList, "value", "text"), new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control col-md-4" } })
                @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.siteNames, new { style = "width: 60%; height: 50px", @class = "never-dirty" })
            </div>
```

I'm using jquery to set the DropDownList to a Multiselect list as follows :-

```
    $('#SiteList').multiselect({
        maxHeight: 400,
        enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering: true,
        includeSelectAllOption: true,
        onSelectAll: function () {
            $('#siteNames').val("All Sites");
        }
    });
```

This bit works OK. Sites are stores in the testarea as follows :-

1:Site 1
2:Site 2

etc.

When loading the form, if the model.siteNames already contains sites, I want to select those sites in the controller so that they are already selected when the form is rendered. This is what I am trying.

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(postModel.siteNames) == false)
    {
        var sites = model.siteNames.Split(nl);
        foreach (var s in sites)
        {
            var siteId = s.Split(':')[0];
            var selected = postModel.siteList.Where(x => x.Value == siteId);
            postModel.siteList.SetSelected(selected);
        }
    }
```

When the form loads there are no list items selected. Any ideas where I'm going wrong ? Thanks.

UPDATE

I couldn't get Orvar's solution to work so I have tried another approach. It seems that the SelectList I was passing to the model didn't have any actual selected items, so that code was wrong.

I have now changed the Type of the list to a MultiSelectList and I am initialising it as follows in the controller :-

```
 model.siteList = new MultiSelectList(siteList, "value", "text", selectedSiteIDs);
```

where selectedIDs is a List of IDs that I want to be selected, and I have verified that this time that the items listed in selectedIDs are set to selected in siteList.

However, in my view the control still does not have any selected items. Code for the control now looks like this :-

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.siteNames, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
    @Html.ListBox("siteList", new SelectList(Model.siteList, "value", "text"), new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control col-md-4", multiple = "multiple" } })
</div>
```

Could it be that the jquery call to multiselect (requred for bootstrap) is clearing the selected items ?

Answer (score 0):

Try and see if the following code can help:

`@Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.SelectedValues, new MultiSelectList(Model.siteList., "value", "text", Model.SelectedValues), "Select Site", new { @class = "chzn-select form-control", multiple = "multiple" })`

https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1194907/Razor-mutliselect-dropdown-set-values-as-selected

Good source here for *Multiple Selections* in mvc:
https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/265/asp-net-mvc-dropdownlists-multiple-selection-and-enum-support